# Using functions before they are declared

Tags: f#

For the sake of using literate programming (i.e. cweb) in F#, I need to be able to forward declare functions (i.e. use them before defining them). I came up with two ways, both of them unpleasing. Can you think of something better (easier to use for the programmer)?

### Nice, but doesn't work with polymorphic functions

```
// This can be ugly
let declare<'a>  = ref Unchecked.defaultof<'a>

// This has to be beautiful
let add = declare<float -> float>

let ``function I want to explain that depends on add`` nums = nums |> Seq.map !add

add := fun x -> x + 1.
```

### Ugly, but works with everything

```
// This can be ugly
type Literate() =
static member Declare<'a, 'b>  (ref : obj ref) (x : 'a) : 'b =
                                    unbox <| (unbox<obj -> obj> !ref)
static member Define<'a, 'b> (func : 'a -> 'b) (ref : obj ref) (f : 'a -> 'b) =
                                    ref := box (unbox<'a> >> f >> box)

// This has to be beautiful
let rec id (x : 'a) : 'a = Literate.Declare idImpl x
and idImpl = ref null

let f () = id 100 + id 200

Literate.Define id idImpl (fun x -> x)
```

Comment: That is anti-idiomatic. Are you sure you cannot document the way you program?

Comment: The reasons for this requirement are worth a post on its own (upcoming), for now let's try to solve the puzzle if there is a better way to do forward function declaration.

Answer (score 3):

I used a tool that follows the same ideas as literate programming when creating [www.tryjoinads.org](http://www.tryjoinads.org). A document is simply a Markdown with code snippets that get turned into an F# source code that you can run and the snippets have to be in a correct order. (In some literate programming tools, the documentation is written in commments, but the idea is the same.)

Now, I think that making your code *more complicated* so that you can write it in a literate programming style (and document it) is introducing a lot of accidental complexity and it is defeating the main purpose of literate programming.

So, if I wanted to solve this problem, I would extend my literate programming tool with some annotation that specifies the order of code blocks that is needed to make the script work (and a simple pre-processing tool can re-order them when generating F# input). You can take a [look at my build script][1] for TryJoinads, which would be fairly easy to extend to do this.

The tool I used for TryJoinads already provides some meta-tags that can be used to hide code blocks from the output, so you can write something like:

```
## This is my page heading

    [hide]
    // This function will be hidden from the generated HTML
    // but it is visible to the F# compiler
    let add a b = a + b 

Here is the description for the other function:

   let functionThatUsesAdd x = add x x

And later on I can repeat `add` with more comments (and I can add an annotation
`module` to avoid conflicts with the previous declaration):

   [module=Demo]
   let add a b =
     // Add a and b
     a + b
```

This also isn't perfect, because you have to duplicate functions, but at least your generated blog post or HTML documentation will not be obscured by things that do not matter. But of course, adding some meta-command like `module` or `hide` to specify order of blocks wouldn't be too hard and it would be a clean solution.

In summary, I think you just need a better literate programming tool, not different F# code or F# langauge.

Comment: If you pre-process the code, you lose intellisense, debugging and the interactive console, unless you are willing to rewrite the whole toolset.If you write the code in the order that the compiler wants it, you lose possibly the main distinctive feature of literate programming. So you are between a rock and an hard place, hence my desire for a way out.

Comment: @user965221 Depends on how you do it. My primitive tool for TryJoinads is focused on writing the Markdown, but you could do it the other way round too - have all Markdown in F# comments, keep the F# file in the required order *but* reorder the generated documentation. IntelliSense would work just fine. For blog posts, I prefer to reorder code snippets, but for documentation, reordering the document sounds like a better way to go.

Comment: You got it. Overall, this is what I'm doing it. But re-ordening the generated document requires that you still write the code in the order that the compiler wants it, not in the order that you with to think about it, which is sub-optimal. Hence my desire for a way to write the code directly in the 'thinking' order, but still keep the compiler happy. I guess my mischievous scheme will become clear when I post about it. - Luca

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why aren't you going all the way and 'doing it properly'?

> Using the function first:
>
> ```
> <<test.fs>>=
> <<add>>
> let inc = add 1
> ```
>
> Declaring the function afterwards:
>
> ```
> <<add>>=
> let add a b = a + b
> ```

Comment: Doing it the knuth way loses IDE, debugger and interactive console (unless you are lucky enouh for them to be literate-enabled). I'm not ready to pay that price :-)

Comment: @user965221 Yeah, I did go some way towards making a REPL-kind of literate programming 'IDE', but never got much further than Alpha. [This blog post](http://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.ch/2010/03/literate-programming-life-cycle.html) (which IIRC was inspired by a question from me) might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

Since functions are first-class objects in F#, you can pass them around instead -- which presents a much nicer (and still immutable) solution than forward references.

```
let dependentFunction f nums = nums |> Seq.map f

let ``function I want to explain that depends on add`` nums =
    dependentFunction (fun x -> x + 1.) nums
```

Also, in most cases you should be able to use currying (partial function application) to simplify the code further but the type inference for `seq<'T>` is a little strange in F# because it's usually used as a flexible type (similar to covariance in C# 4.0). To illustrate:

```
// This doesn't work because of type inference on seq<'T>,
// but it should work with most other types.
let ``function I want to explain that depends on add`` =
    dependentFunction (fun x -> x + 1.)
```

Finally, a good rule of thumb for using `ref` or `mutable` in F# is that if you're only going to assign the value once (to initialize it), there's probably a cleaner, more functional way to write that code (passing the value as a function parameter (as above) and `lazy` are two such approaches). Obviously there are exceptions to this rule, but even then they should be used very sparingly.

Comment: See answer to Ramon Snir. I know I can do this, but it is too intrusive as it changes the signature of ``function I want to explain that depends on add``.

Comment: No, it doesn't -- the signature of `function I want to explain that depends on add` is `seq<float> -> seq<float>` in both your first example and my first example.

Comment: This is just because you renamed ``function I want to explain that depends on add`` to ``dependentFunction``. Otherwise your solution is identical to Ramon and requires to pass the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, this is wrong (and you should publish a blog article, or a FPish post, about why you're doing this)), but here is my take:

```
let ``function I want to explain that depends on add``
      (add : float -> float) = nums |> Seq.map add

let add = (+) 1.

let ``function I want to explain that depends on add`` = ``function I want to explain that depends on add`` add
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified it in the original question. I know that I can solve it by passing a functions as a parameter, but that is too intrusive in my scenarios. I really want to forward declare a function as in the question text (aka ``function I want to explain that depends on add`` shouldn't take an argument).

Comment: Use C? This isn't possible in the ML language family. **Isn't possible**, and *shouldn't be*.

Comment: I know that the language doesn't allow it. I was looking for a trick, akin to the ones I suggested, to fake it. As an aside, I'm not sure what is conceptually wrong with forward function declaration to elicit such a strong response on your side. Cheers.

Comment: @user965221: I agree with Ramon that defining functions (and more so modules/types) before using them makes it much easier to manage dependencies. I'd consider dependency management the central challenge of most larger projects.

Comment: Defining functions before using them doesn't help much with dependency management. If you don't define a function, your program doesn't even compile.

Comment: @user965221: I was referring to "before" in space, not time. Since F# doesn't support forward declarations, project files in Solution Explorer represent tiers of abstraction, starting with the lowest at the top to the highest at the bottom. It's a much simpler conceptual model than a C# project affords.